# Sending bluetooth data between Android and Hololens

Tags: android, bluetooth, hololens

I have created an application to Android and Microsoft Hololens, where it is possible to send some GPS-data with bluetooth from an Android-phone to a Hololens (with Bluetooth LE Advertiser) and that works allright. But when I am trying to send other data from Hololens to Android, I have a problem that Android-phone can't discover Hololens, although these devices are paired. Is it even possible to send data from Hololens with bluetooth, or is there only something wrong in my code? Does Bluetooth LE Advertising support two-way data transfering?

Comment: I am also looking for similar usecase. I want to connect my android device with hololens and do one way transmission from android device to hololens. Can you suggest how listener code should be on hololens side to get the data.

Comment: @Venkatesh have you had success in bluetooth pairing of holo lens and android? Would you be able to share on github?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have a BluetoothConnected thread in your android app with an InputStream (mine is mmInStream). Try using this as your 'run' function in the thread:

```
public void run() {

        System.out.println("BT THREAD RUNNING");

        mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()
        InputStreamReader mmInStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(mmInStream);
        BufferedReader mmReader = new BufferedReader(mmInStreamReader);

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.

        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream.

                Thread.sleep(100);
                String s = mmReader.readLine();
                Thread.sleep(100);
                //Static class that handles the response
                BluetoothCommunications.responseHandler(s);



            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Input stream was disconnected" + e);
                main.disconnected();
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```